# How to break up an array into sub arrays?

Tags: arrays, ruby, object

I am trying to manipulate an array of arrays, in such a way that I have access to each individual array as a variable.

In my code I am storing 7 different entries of user input in the form of an of an array of arrays. These entries are two values separated by a space i.e. user inputs `1` followed by a space followed by a `4` providing the array `["1","4"]`

```
#user prompt repeated 7 times    
puts "enter segments: "
e1 = gets.chomp.split
#etc...

entries = [e1, e2, e3, e4, e5, e6, e7] #e.g. 'eX' may be of form ["n", "n2"]
new_values = []


@dict = [2,3,1,2,3,2,3,3,1]
entries.each do |convert|
    convert.each do |get_integers|
        get_integers.each do |get_strings|
            new_values << @dict[get_strings.to_i]
        end
    end
end

array_of_new = new_values.slice(2)
```

I am trying to:

- Convert the elements from each subarray in `entries` to integers
- Then in the `entries` subarrays I want to replace each element `i` with `@dict[i]`

The code I have does all of the above but I end up with a flattened array with all the new values.

How do I break the final array back up into a new array of arrays (so with the same structure as the `entries` array)? I tried using the `slice` method, but this is just giving me back the element in the position I am slicing.

Also, I am positive there is a better way to accomplish what I am doing, so if anyone has any advice, I am open to it!

Comment: Does something like `new_values.map { |x| Array(x) }` do what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Try something like this:*

```
entries = []
7.times do 
    puts "enter segments: "
    entries << gets.chomp.split.map!{|e| e.to_i }
end

@dict = [2,3,1,2,3,2,3,3,1]
array_of_new = []

entries.each do |sub_array|
    s_arr = []
    sub_array.each do |element| 
        s_arr << @dict[element]
    end
    array_of_new << s_arr
end

p array_of_new
```

---

*If you wanted to use the `each_slice` method then you could do something like this:*

```
entries = []
7.times do 
    puts "enter segments: "
    entries << gets.chomp.split.map!{|e| e.to_i }
end


@dict = [2,3,1,2,3,2,3,3,1]
arr = []

entries.each do |sub_array|
    sub_array.each do |element| 
        arr << @dict[element]
    end
end

array_of_new = []
arr.each_slice(2) {|s| array_of_new << s }                          

p array_of_new
```

---

*Update: An even shorter and smarter way would be to actually transform the `entries` array instead of having to create new container arrays:*

```
entries = []
7.times do 
    puts "enter segments: "
    entries << gets.chomp.split.map!{|e| e.to_i }
end

@dict = [2,3,1,2,3,2,3,3,1]

entries.each do |sub_array|
    sub_array.map!{|e| @dict[e] }
end

p entries
```

Comment: This is exceptional. Thank you!

Comment: @Jbur43 Glad I could help. Just added a third way which you may find useful too.